# Should HTML email template use table element for the layout?

Tags: html-email

I have seen bunch of HTML email templates example and all of them use `<table>` element for layout. Is there any specific reason for using `<table>`? I tried making one without it and it works for me. Should I be worried that it might break for someone else with different browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to this old post([why-is-it-still-recommended-to-use-tables-for-email-structure](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1443-why-is-it-still-recommended-to-use-tables-for-email-structure)) and some of my own experiments:

We can definitely use HTML tags and not just `<table>` tag. It gets rendered well in modern browsers. I have personally experimented with Chrome ( which most probably means it works on all chromium based browsers ) and Safari.

Another thing I noticed is, the email clients stripped the template and removed all tags except the main content. In other words, it only rendered what's inside the `<body>` tag and removed other tags like `<html>`, `<head>` including the `<body>` tag itself. So I don't use those tags in my template at all.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason tables are still used nowadays is to support Outlook 2007/2010/2013. Those versions use Microsoft Word engine to render HTML, and it's quite a mess. It has a limited support for CSS (no float or position for example), and some CSS properties are only supported on some specific HTML elements. For example, padding is supported on a , but not on a . And even when you could theorically use padding on more semantical elements (like  tags), or use margin on  elements instead, Word's rendering engine is still massively bugged and can have unpredictable behavior with such HTML and CSS code. Thus, developers find it easier to just use  instead.

But here's the thing : if you don't feel like you need to support Outlook 2007/2010/2013, then you can absolutely ditch tables and use better code instead. And even if you need to support it, simple one-column layouts can be done without tables. The reason your template works in Outlook 2011 is that this version (for Mac only) uses WebKit rendering engine (just like in Safari or Apple Mail).

Comment: It seems you have copied your answer from this post:
https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1443-why-is-it-still-recommended-to-use-tables-for-email-structure